# Declare a global array before main() without knowing it's size in c

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

How to declare an array without knowing its size?
The size will be calculated inside the main function (buffer_size).
This code is not working, the size is always 2.

I am running the code here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *data_array = NULL;


int main()
{   
    int buffer_size = 4;
    data_array = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(int));
    int size = sizeof(data_array)/sizeof(data_array[0]);

    printf(">> Size %d\n", size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        printf(">> data %d\n", data_array[i]);
    }
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

UPD: So, the declaration of array actually working. The issue is with the way I was checking the array size.

Comment: `sizeof` of a pointer will always return the size of the pointer itself, not whatever data it might point to. If you need the size, you need to store it in a variable (like your `buffer_size` variable) and pass it to the functions that needs it.

Comment: `data_array` is a pointer, so `sizeof` on it is giving the size of a pointer. On the other hand, you already know the right size - it is the one you have passed to `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks, guys, for answering, but it didn't help too much. I have no experience with C language, still have no idea how to fix the code...

Is it even possible to implement?

Comment: Your `size` should be equal to `buffer_size`.

Comment: >> Your size should be equal to buffer_size

It should, but the size of the array is 2...

`int size = sizeof(data_array)/sizeof(data_array[0]);` 

here I am checking if my array is of a proper size, maybe I am doing it wrong...

Comment: The two first commets are explaining why. If you want `size` to be equal to `buffer_size`, you simply use `size=buffer_size`. That is, there is no magical way to get the size of `malloc`ed memory, but you can keep track of it from the moment you have allocated it.

Comment: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is only useful when `a` is an array.  In your case, `data_array` is poorly named, because it is *not* an array.

Comment: You are trying to calculate the value of `buffer_size` which you already have. Try to think before copy-paste (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you may not declare a variable length array with static storage duration.

Here there is declared a pointer instead of an array

```
int *data_array = NULL;
```

The result of the expression with the sizeof operator in this declaration

```
int size = sizeof(data_array)/sizeof(data_array[0]);
```

that is equivalent to

```
int size = sizeof( int * )/sizeof( int );
```

is always equal to either `2` or `1` dependent of the used system.

You already stored the size of the allocated array in the variable `buffer_size`.

```
int buffer_size = 4;
data_array = malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(int));
```

So use it anywhere further as for example in this statement

```
printf(">> Size %d\n", buffer_size);
```

Pay attention to that this for loop

```
for(int i=0; i < buffer_size; i++){
    printf(">> data %d\n", data_array[i]);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the allocated array was not initialized.

Comment: I think you mean `sizeof(int *)/sizeof(int)` is (almost) always equal to 2 or 1.

Comment: Thanks, Vlad,

So, my code is working, I just checking the size of the array in a wrong way!

Comment: @Max You are right. I mean the size of the pointer.:)